# Почему кнопка не видит публичную функции моего скрипта Unity?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть скрипт "InventoryManager", класс в нём публичный, наследуется от MonoBehaviour
В нём есть функция: 
`public void Rays(Ray ray, RaycastHit hit)`

Но UI button по какой-то причине не видит эту функцию, вопрос почему?(Я закинул всё как надо, скрипт на объекте, а уже обект прицепил в поле On Click. Например если написать: public void Awake(), её будет видно.)
Ray ray, RaycastHit hit Объявляются в Update()

Comment: В BUtton не отображаются функции с больше чем одним аргументом

Comment: @Максим Фисман а как с этим жить?
В данном случае я могу объявить ray и hit в private в самом начале, и потом лишь присвоить значение, и тогда мне не придётся писать public void Rays(Ray ray, RaycastHit hit) а только public void Rays(), но, там получится не везде

Comment: Ну, вот так как-то...

Comment: @GHEB, а каким таким волшебным образом, извиняюсь спросить ты в инспекторе укажешь аргументы `Ray` и `RaycastHit`?